# How to create XML dynamically (java)?

Tags: java, xml, list

I'm getting a list in java that contains name of variables and their types.
I want to generate xsd from this list, but I understand that I have to create xml before.

so how do I create xml from list in Java?

Comment: can you please edit your question and add an example to illustrate your list and the xml you want to generate? There are hundreds of different ways to generate a xml in Java.

Comment: Why do you need to generate an XML? I create XSDs with no XML, but I just create them manually

Answer (score 2):

The key is separating your list into a class to hold it . Once that is done you can work on converting it to and from XML. You can read more about XML [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/)

A good tool to do this is [xstream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4077731/1255713):

Heres a good post to show you how to use Xstream [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4077731/1255713)

Comment: it can't be done since the list is dynamic and is different in each run - different variable names, different types.