# Deserialization with XStream - ArrayList stay null

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I have a problem with the deserialization with XStream (from a XML to a java object).

The deserialization works well, except for the repeatable elements (which must turn into a List)...

My XML :

```
<DATA>
    <ANNUAIRES>
        <REC_ANNUAIRE>
            <NOPERS>1815985</NOPERS>
            <NOM>Dubois A. (Evilard)</NOM>
            <LIGNEADR1>DUBOIS A.</LIGNEADR1>
        </REC_ANNUAIRE>
        <REC_ANNUAIRE>
            <NOPERS>0229984</NOPERS>
            <NOM>Dubois Abel (La Chaux-de-Fonds)</NOM>
            <LIGNEADR1>DUBOIS ABEL</LIGNEADR1>
        </REC_ANNUAIRE>
        <REC_ANNUAIRE>
            <NOPERS>0013717</NOPERS>
            <NOM>Dubois Achim (Corpataux-Magnedens)</NOM>
            <LIGNEADR1>DUBOIS ACHIM</LIGNEADR1>
        </REC_ANNUAIRE>
        <REC_ANNUAIRE>
            <NOPERS>1602681</NOPERS>
            <NOM>Dubois Adrienne (Orvin)</NOM>
            <LIGNEADR1>DUBOIS ADRIENNE</LIGNEADR1>
        </REC_ANNUAIRE>
        <REC_ANNUAIRE>
            <NOPERS>0384177</NOPERS>
            <NOM>Dubois Agnes (Thun 7)</NOM>
            <LIGNEADR1>DUBOIS AGNES</LIGNEADR1>
        </REC_ANNUAIRE>
        <REC_ANNUAIRE>
            <NOPERS>1424276</NOPERS>
            <NOM>Dubois Agnes (Bussigny-Lausanne)</NOM>
            <LIGNEADR1>DUBOIS AGNES</LIGNEADR1>
        </REC_ANNUAIRE>
        <NBREC EOF="False">50</NBREC>
        <DUREE_EXECSQL>0</DUREE_EXECSQL>
        <DUREE_BUILDXML>0</DUREE_BUILDXML>
    </ANNUAIRES>
</DATA>
```

My XStream Code :

```
XStream xs = new XStream();

xs.alias("DATA", PojoPersonne.class);
xs.alias("REC_ANNUAIRE", Personne.class);

xs.aliasField("ANNUAIRES", PojoPersonne.class, "annuaire");
xs.aliasField("NOPERS", Personne.class, "idPersonne");
xs.aliasField("NOM", Personne.class, "identite");
xs.aliasField("STATUS", PojoPersonne.class, "status");


xs.addImplicitCollection(PojoPersonne.class, "listePersonne");


PojoPersonne pojo = (PojoPersonne)xs.fromXML(xml);
System.out.println(pojo);
pojo.afficheListe();
```

My PojoPersonne class :

```
public class PojoPersonne {
    private String annuaire;
    private List<Personne> listePersonne = new ArrayList<>();
    private String status;

    public PojoPersonne(String annuaire, ArrayList<Personne> listePersonne, String status){
        this.annuaire = annuaire;
        this.listePersonne = listePersonne;
        this.status = status;
    }
    public PojoPersonne(){
        this.listePersonne = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

So the problem is from the listePersonne ArrayList... it's always null (or empty if I use `XStream xs = new XStream(new PureJavaReflectionProvider());`)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a class for the ArrayList and use:

```
xstream.addImplicitCollection(Annuaries.class, "ANNUAIRES");
```

Also lose the `<DATA></DATA>` you don't need it.
Should be something like explained in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077071/how-to-convert-list-of-object-to-xml-doc-using-xstream)

Comment: Thanks, but I can't do without `<DATA></DATA>`, if I try to ignore the root element, I have an Exception (`CannotResolveClassException: DATA`). But with your help, it's much better... Nearly. I have another problem now. When I try to recover the result (ListePersonne pojo = (`ListePersonne)xs.fromXML(xml);`), the cast doesn't work (`vaudoiseLib.pojo.personne.ListePersonne cannot be cast to vaudoiseLib.model.personne.Personne`). I think it's maybe because of my XML (`<DATA><ANNUAIRES> ... </ANNUAIRES></DATA>`) but I don't know how I can resolve that...

Comment: P.S. I just try too delete the DATA root element "manually" from the XML (so I use ANNUAIRES like root) and everything works well... But I cannot edit the XML, so I have to do with this.. :( I don't have any idea...

Comment: Just do another class, Data.class. This class has what? An annuaries instance. I'll show you a working example when I'm back at the office

Comment: Thanks ! I understand well how that work ! Everything is ok now =)