# java - Creating multilple objects with XStreams

Tags: java, xstream

As shown below, I have a POJO class with setters and getters:

```
public class InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage  {

    private String InvoiceReference;
    private String ABSReference;
    private String Currency;
    private double InvoiceAmount;
    private double PaidAmount;
    private double BalanceAmount;
    private Date ValueDate;
    private String Remarks;

}
```

and below is the class in which the above is being referenced:

```
public class Mail {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private  InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage;

    public InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage getInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage() {
        return invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage;
    }

    public void setInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage(
            InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage) {
        this.invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage = invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage;
    }

}
```

I am using xstream to generate the xml from the object. I have no problem creating a single object in java as shown below:

```
public class InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessagetest {

    InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage = new InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage();
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setInvoiceReference("S15");
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setABSReference("IRMA1");
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setCurrency("GBP");
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setInvoiceAmount(25746);
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setPaidAmount(18245);
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setBalanceAmount(90);
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setValueDate(new Date());
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setRemarks("abc");


    Mail m = new Mail();
    m.setInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage);
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.alias("brokermail",Mail.class);
    String abc = xstream.toXML(m);
}
```

How would I proceed in creating multiple objects? Should I add them to a list and then pass it to xstream? please advise how can I change my mail class to store multiple objects of InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage  class Below is my attempt:

```
InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1 = new InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage();
invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setInvoiceReference("S93159");
invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setABSReference("IRM9311");
invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setCurrency("GBP");
invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setInvoiceAmount(257646);
invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setPaidAmount(12475);
invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setBalanceAmount(0);
invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setValueDate(new Date());
invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setRemarks("abrtc");


InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage2 = new InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage();
invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setInvoiceReference("S6315");
invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setABSReference("IR11");
invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setCurrency("GBP");
invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setInvoiceAmount(266546);
invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setPaidAmount(12645);
invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setBalanceAmount(0);
invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setValueDate(new Date());
invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setRemarks("abcdgdg");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [XStream arrayList to and from XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016334/xstream-arraylist-to-and-from-xml)

Comment: I have answered in your other thread. For future: do not duplicate posts!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xstream

Answer (score 0):

I seems fairly obvious. Since `Mail` can only contain one `InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage` you will need to create a second 'Mail` object (or reuse the first after generating the XML) to persist the second 'InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage' object.

```
Mail m1 = new Mail();
Mail m2 = new Mail()

XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.alias("brokermail",Mail.class);

m1.setInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1);
m2.setInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage2);

String abc1 = xstream.toXML(m1);
String abc2 = xstream.toXML(m2);
```

... OR ...

```
Mail m1 = new Mail();

XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.alias("brokermail",Mail.class);

m1.setInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1);

String abc1 = xstream.toXML(m1);

m1.setInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage2);

String abc2 = xstream.toXML(m1);
```

Comment: @Breet Thanks but please advise what about if in class mail i could have use arraylist to store objects of class invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage

Comment: I you have control over the design of `Mail`, and it makes sense to allow more than one copy of `InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage ` per `Mail` object; then go right ahead.

Comment: Thanks please advise what changes i need to do in mail class then if possible you can change the mail class i have posted above itself, Thanks in advance

Comment: @ndsfd see my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this version of `Mail` as a starting point:

```
public class Mail {
    private  List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> invoiceReferenceNotificationMessages = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> getInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessages() {
        return invoiceReferenceNotificationMessages;
    }

    public void addInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage(InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage) {
        this.invoiceReferenceNotificationMessages.add(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage);
    }

    public void addInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessages(List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> invoiceReferenceNotificationMessages) {
        this.invoiceReferenceNotificationMessages = invoiceReferenceNotificationMessages;
    }
}
```

You can change/add methods as you like...

Comment: Thanks a lot in this you have provided bot h the options to add single or multiple InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage class objects can you please advise now in the main class where i am creating the objects of InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage shall i add the objetc in a list please advise now how i will create the objects pleaseThanks inadvance

Comment: Mail m1 = new Mail();

XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.alias("brokermail",Mail.class);

m1.setInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1);
String abc1 = xstream.toXML(m1);
m1.setInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage2);
String abc2 = xstream.toXML(m1);

Comment: It is up to you with the given the methods above. You can create your own list of  `InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage` outside of `Mail` and pass the list to `Mail` or create and pass individual `InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage` to `Mail`. I prefer the second option when given the chance.

Comment: i have use this approch..List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> invoiceReferenceNotificationMessagest = new ArrayList<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>();
  invoiceReferenceNotificationMessagest.add(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage);  invoiceReferenceNotificationMessagest.add(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1); Mail m = new Mail();
  m.addInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessages(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessagest);
  XStream xstream = new XStream();
  xstream.alias("brokermail",Mail.class);
  String abc = xstream.toXML(m);